# Tableview and adding buttons to it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 2 questions.

1.) I have a tableView, and it will have more than 100 rows (of data). But i will only display 10 records at a time. when the user scrolls down and below the 10th row i want to add a button, which says `load the next 10 records` and `load the previous 10 records`. How do i add these buttons ? note: that these buttons only appear when you scroll down to the last record of your table view (I found a similar example in iTunes too)

2.) I need those 2 buttons to have an arrow shape [(As a Navigation button)](http://img.skitch.com/20100513-m9b9g67ftfh8bisgbj3mib9sex.jpg)

How do i get this done **programatically**. (I will not be using the interface builder to create this)

Comment: Where do you want those buttons?

Comment: after the 10th row has been displayed.

Comment: Then just add one more row with those buttons and that's it...

Comment: Can you show me how to do it programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these steps and code.

1) create Button

2) Background Image for the UIButton

3) Add target (getNext10List)

4) Create footer view

5) Add the view in your cell.

```
    UIButton *pagingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    pagingButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 316, 35);
    pagingButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"next10Holder@2x.png"];
    [pagingButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pagingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getNext10List) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //create a footer view on the bottom of the tabeview
    footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 316, 45)];
    [footerView addSubview:pagingButton];

    messageTableView.tableFooterView = footerView;     
    [[self view] addSubview:messageTableView];
```

Comment: So i should add these codes in the ViewDidLoad method? I need to have 2 buttons so i will have to create another button and add it to the `messageTableView` ? I need to get a `UINavigationButton` shaped button here, how should i do this ? (Sorry for these questions, i am a beginner)

Comment: You can add this code when you done loading your 10 row cell and then reload the tableview. I add this code when i finish my data loading. I have a flag that will tell me actualPageCount. If you dont have anymore data to loa then just, removeFromSuperview your button and tablefotterview

Comment: Ok, data are populated to cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method, so once all the data is populated i should add the above code you supplied ? In what method should i put it ? (what is the method that gets fired after `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ? Should i add it in that ?)

Comment: Do this, add selector in viewDidLoad (    [self performSelector:@selector(getMessages) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
). In getMessages function reload the data first and then add the code i supplied.

Comment: "reload data first " means to reload the tableView ?

Comment: Yup. Reload the tableview first or after that code, just try it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some custom UITableViewCell subclass. Something like that:

.h file:

```
#define kBackButtonPressedNotification    @"kBackButtonPressedNotification"
#define kForwardButtonPressedNotification @"kForwardButtonPressedNotification"

@interface ButtonsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
@private
    UIButton* _backButton;
    UIButton* _forwardButton;
}
@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation ButtonsTableViewCell
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self){
        _backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        _backButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30); //put numbers that are good for you
        [_backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someBackButtonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_backButton];

        _forwardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        _forwardButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30); //put numbers that are good for you
        [_forwardButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someForwardButtonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_forwardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(forwardPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_forwardButton];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)backPressed{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:kBackButtonPressedNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)forwardPressed{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:kForwardButtonPressedNotification object:nil];
}
@end
```

In your controller's `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;` method return number of rows + 1 (for additional row with buttons). In the `-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` check the indexPath.row and when it's the last one -> return instance of that custom cell. And of course you'll need to register for those notifications, let's say like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourBackMethod) name:kBackButtonPressedNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourForwardMethod) name:kForwardButtonPressedNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
}
```

Don't forget to provide proper implementation for `yourBackMethod` and `yourForwardMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is row 11 ad a subview with your buttons on it to the contentViewof the cell.

Comment: How do i do it ? and some times if there aren't enough records to display (say if it has 3 records then we should add the buttons to the 4th row). Can you provide a sample code if possible ?